# Loop for different values

Tags: coding-style

I have the following:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
 n= 3;
 T = Transpose[Table[{t^i}, {i, 0, n}]];
 B = DiagonalMatrix[Range[n], 1, n + 1];
 Print[ T, B]
```

I want to have a loop for different values of n say n=1 to 100, so I can get T and B.

Comment: Why don't you just create functions?
`T[n_Integer] := {Array[t^#&, n + 1, 0]}` and `B[n_Integer] := DiagonalMatrix[Range[n], 1, n + 1]` then use them in a table like `Table[{T[n], B[n]},{n,1,100}]`

Comment: many thank, in fact I have long code depend on n, currently I am running it for each n, I was trying to get loop for n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting it in another `Table`:

```
Table[
 {Transpose[Table[{t^i}, {i, 0, n}]],
  DiagonalMatrix[Range[n], 1, n + 1]},
 {n, 1, 100}]
```

This will give you a list of pairs {T, B}, and you can specify start and end values for `n`.

If you don't want a list but just printed expressions, you can use `Do` and `Print`:

```
Do[
 Print[{Transpose[Table[{t^i}, {i, 0, n}]],
   DiagonalMatrix[Range[n], 1, n + 1]}],
 {n, 1, 100}]
```